# Is there any way to avoid comma in start and end of string using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not very good at regex and I need 1 regex for validating the comma in start and end of string. I am doing string to array conversion.

Valid string will be like this,

```
var data = test,test1,123,H345TG;
```

It should not allow the following cases and return false,

```
var data = ,test,test1
var data = test,test1,
var data = test,,test2,,test,
```

Tried the below regex, but not working,

```
/(?:,[A-Za-z]+)|(?:[A-Za-z],)/
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does there have to be a comma present?

Comment: An alternative to validating the string with regex: make it valid instead: https://codepen.io/3rror404/pen/OJyyOVX?editors=1111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
^\w+(,\w+)*$
```

Explanation: If there is some `,` character, it should be followed by some alphabet or number character(s).

```js
var pattern = /^\w+(,\w+)*$/;

console.log(pattern.test('test'));
console.log(pattern.test('test,test1,123,H345TG'));
console.log(pattern.test(',test,test1'));
console.log(pattern.test('test,test1,'));
console.log(pattern.test('test,,test2,,test,'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you tried `(?:,[A-Za-z]+)|(?:[A-Za-z],)` matches either a comma and 1+ chars a-z or the other way around and will get you partial matches.

You are not matching the digits, and if you want to validate the whole string you could use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string.

If there has to be a comma present, repeat the non capturing group 1 or more times using `+`, else use `*` if only chars a-z and digits are also ok.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:,[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZoexT/1)

```js
const regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:,[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/;
[
  "test,test1,123,H345TG",
  "test",
  ",test,test1",
  "test,test1,",
  "test,,test2,,test,"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s}: ${regex.test(s)}`));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But also it should pass, if var data = test;

Comment: @Deepak I have updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick:
`/^[^,].*[^,]$/`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/gCvO0r/1

Answer (score -2):

```js
console.log(
`var data = test,test1,123,H345TG;
var data = ,test,test1
var data = test,test1,
var data = test,,test2,,test,`
.split("\n")
.map(s => !!s.match(/^var\s+data\s*=\s*(?!,)(?!.*,;?$)(?!.*,,)[\w,]+;?$/))
)
```